# function send email with attachment error

Tags: php, html, email, mime, email-attachments

I'm trying to create from sending mail with attachment file via PHP, but there is an error, when mail sent to mail box the message arrive with out any attachments here screen shot of mailbox

[image]

```
<?php
function mail_file($to, $from, $subject, $body, $file){

    $boundary = md5(rand());

    $headers = array(
        'MIME-Version: 1.0',
        "From: {$from}",
        "Content Type : multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$boundary}\""

                    );

$message = array(
"--{$boundary}",
'Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"',
'Content-transfer-Encoding: 7-bit',
'',
chunk_split($body),
"--{$boundary}",
"Content-Type: {file['type']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"",
"Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$file['name']}\"",
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
'',
@chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file['path']))),
"--{$boundary}--"
);

@mail($to, $subject, implode("\r\n", $message), implode("\r\n", $headers));     

        }

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =='POST'){
    $file = array (

    'name' => $_FILES['file']['name'],
    'size' => $_FILES['file']['size'],
    'type' => $_FILES['file']['type'],
    'path' => $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']
    );



    mail_file('fahmy.farahat@gmail.com', 'File from <fahmy.farahat@gmail.com>', 'a file up', $body, $file);
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>send mail</title>
</head>

<body>


<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Name</label><br />

<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<br /><br />


<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="email file" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not sure, what may be the problem, but why not you use any mail library for sending email with attachments? It will need less code, and provide ability to attach files with, and you will be not facing such issues. One popular lib is Swift http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: Well, you say "there is an error"... what _is_ the error? What do the logfiles say?

Comment: Also in such cases you should always first dump the final components of the payload into a file and check if they really contain what you expect. Add that information to the question above.

Comment: As an aside, why do you create a multipart when you have no content for the text body part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mail header should read `Content-Type`, not `Content Type`.

Comment: Does this mean that you cannot see the file size in your mail client only? Or that you cannot even save the file from the email?

Comment: file arrive to mail with 0k size

Comment: Sorry, but that's really ambiguous answer.